# How do I make a dropdown extend to the left?

Tags: css

This is my first post here after many visits. Hello!

I am trying to make pop-up annotations on an image. I am using the CSS dropdown menu behavior to do this. You can see my example [here](http://www.troyoxford.com/paint/)

When you hover over the tip icon on the left, the container expands to reveal the text. But for the tip icon on the right, the text box extends outside of the image boundary.

How do I make the text box appear to the left of the icon so it stays within the image?
I used margin-left with a negative value but it also moves the tip icon.

Here is my code:
    
    
        test

```
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css"> 

.container {
z-index: 1000;
width: 15px;
height: 18px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}
.container:hover {
width: 200px;
height: auto;
}

.copy {
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #ffcc99;
}

#painting {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 750px;
height: 530px;
background: url(painting.jpg) top left no-repeat #ffffff;
}

#tip1 {
left: 185px;
top: 60px;
}

#tip2 {
left: 698px;
top: 290px;
}

</style>


<div id="tip1" class="container">
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="tip_icon.png">
    </div>

    <div class="copy">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras libero ante, faucibus ac dictum eget, mollis ac erat. In porta velit vitae arcu vehicula ornare lacinia turpis accumsan. Quisque nec ligula non ligula elementum ultrices. Suspendisse commodo suscipit dapibus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tip2" class="container">
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="tip_icon.png">
    </div>

    <div class="copy">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras libero ante, faucibus ac dictum eget, mollis ac erat. In porta velit vitae arcu vehicula ornare lacinia turpis accumsan. Quisque nec ligula non ligula elementum ultrices. Suspendisse commodo suscipit dapibus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="painting">
    </div>

</body>
```

I am still learning CSS so I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/CwgDQ/1/ 
Instead of overflowing the content of the container hide it by default and show on `:hover`. 
Add `position:absolute` to `.copy` and `#tip2 .copy { ...; right:0 }`  should do the trick.

**EDIT (copy of CSS)**

```
.container {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
}

.container:hover {
    height: auto;
}

.container .copy {
    display:none;
}

.container:hover .copy {
    display:block;
    width: 200px;
}

.copy {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ffcc99;
    position:absolute;
}

#painting {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 750px;
    height: 530px;
    background: url(http://www.troyoxford.com/paint/painting.jpg) top left no-repeat #ffffff;
}

#tip1 {
    left: 185px;
    top: 60px;
}

#tip2 {
    left: 698px;
    top: 290px;
}

#tip2 .copy {
    right:0
}
```

Comment: Ah, very nice. I didn't know you could do something like `.container:hover .copy`. Much better than my hacked solution :)

Comment: I didn't know that was possible either. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
.container {
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 15px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.copy {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ffcc99;
}

#painting {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 750px;
    height: 530px;
    background: url(painting.jpg) top left no-repeat #ffffff;
}

#tip1 {
    left: 185px;
    top: 60px;
}

#tip2 {
    left: 698px;
    top: 290px;
}

#tip2 .copy {
    position: relative;
    left: -185px;
}
```

Note that it's a little bit hacky, the way that the `copy` sections are being hidden at the moment, since you're just making them tiny, and hiding the overflow.

There might be a clever CSS way to achieve it "properly", but I'd be inclined to use a little bit of javascript, so that when you mouse-over one element, it shows another...

In answer to your main question, combined use of `position: relative` and using a negative `left` offset did the trick. For more information on relative positioning, see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's nice to see there is more than one solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a jquery plugin to manage the tooltips because with CSS alone you can't account for different screen resolutions, so forcing the popup to the left or right can potentially force it off the screen. This is a great plugin that can determine the position of the mouse, and screen to show the popup in clear view.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've never used jquery or javascript but I would like to learn.